# In XlSM excel workbook how to remove data from some columns without affecting formula and its value in the columns in POI

Tags: excel, vba

Working on XLSM workbook in that on im trying to remove data from columns leaving formula containing columns using POI.how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please clarify the question, are you looking for vba code that will remove the contents of all cells on a worksheet that do not contain a Formula?

the following code will remove all non-formulas from the range A1:Z100

```
for each c in Range("A1:Z100").cells
If c.HasFormula = False then c.ClearContents
next
```

Hope this helps :)